# Serving the static content (EC2) and REST services (API Gateway) from the same address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a website which I serve using express running in an EC2 instance. But this EC2 serves only the static content (html, js, css) and the dynamic part comes from API Gateway. Right now, these two have different IPs (and domains) which means that I have to deal with CORS problems accessing API Gateway from the web pages. If I could somehow serve the static content and dynamic one through the same address, that would be much better.

The way I see it, this can be done in two ways. I can serve both of them on the same host but different ports which I'm not sure if it's going to solve the same CORS problem or not. But another way which I'm sure it will not face the CORS problem is serving API Gateway under some specific sub-folder. Like `http://example.com/api` while the static content is served from any url except that.

Does anyone know how can I do this? Is CloudFront what I need? Or Elastic Load Balancer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CloudFront is what you need for this scenario.

Application Load Balancer can also do path-based routing, but it doesn't support API Gateway as a target.

By default, CloudFront can route requests under a single domain to the correct choice from up to 25 destinations, using up to 25 path (matching) patterns (both of these limits can be increased by request, but it sounds like for now, you only need 2 of each, `/api/*` to the API, and the default `*` route to EC2).  You can also leverage this setup to put some static content in an S3 bucket and take some load off of the servers in EC2.

For this configuration, you will want to configure your API Gateway deployment with a *regional* endpoint, not an *edge optimized* endpoint.   This is because edge optimized endpoints already use part of the CloudFront infrastructure (a part to which you have no ability to configure), so using an edge-optimized endpoint behind your own CloudFront distribution sends each request and response through the CloudFront network twice, increasing latency.